# Prevent componenet from loading before guard completes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to stop a component from loading before guard completes?

**Problem**

My components load before guard retrieves relevant information about user thus failing checks on load.

My current setup is as follows:

AppRouting Module

```
{
    path: 'sub', component: MasterComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }    
    ]
  },
```

**AuthGuard - canActivateChild Method**

```
canActivateChild(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.secService.isAuthorized()
      .map((profilePresent: boolean) => {
        if (!profilePresent) {
          this.secService.getProfile().subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              sessionStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(data));

              return false;
            }
          );

          return true;
        }

        this.secService.redirectToAuthorization();
        return false;
      });
  }
```

In my **Dashboard.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() {
var name = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('profile')).name;

console.info(name);
}
```

This all throws a error on console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Tracking it i noticed the guard doesn't complete before the component loads hence the error (it doesn't exist at time).

Any ideas on how to manage this

Comment: There're also `canLoad`, `CanActivate` and `Resolve`. Maybe one of them will help you.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it correctly you need the Observable returned from `canActivateChild` to complete after you retrieve data from `this.secService.getProfile()`.

You just need to restructure your Observable chain and not make a nested subscription:

```
return this.secService.isAuthorized()
  .concatMap((profilePresent: boolean) => {
    if (!profilePresent) {
      return this.secService.getProfile()
        .do(data => sessionStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(data))
        .mapTo(true); // I'm not sure what you really need to do here
    }

    this.secService.redirectToAuthorization()
    return Observable.of(false);
  });
```

Notice that you can't return a value from `subscribe` call, so I'd don't know what exactly you wanted to do but I hope you get the point.

Comment: still loads component before it receives the data back. Doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Can you make a demo? What do you mean by "loads" anyway? It shows the component or it loads the bundle or what?

Comment: Not easily. As in it triggers ngOnInit() before getProfile() returns value. From my understanding the path shouldn't even be loaded before canActivateChild returns a value true. Yet here we are, its not returning true but never the less its still loading the children.